# ifelse() returns NA for certain true/false class values

Tags: r

Is there some restrictions of the types of values ifelse() can return?

For:

```
v = c(1,2)
l1 = list(11)
l2 = list(22)
> ifelse(v==1, l1, l2)
[[1]]
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1] 22
```

as expected, but:

```
hp0 = fp_text_lite() 
hp = fp_text_lite(bold = TRUE, shading.color = "yellow" ) 
ifelse(v==1, hp, hp0)

[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `?ifelse` help page, the value returned by `ifelse` is

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as `test` and data values from the values of `yes` or `no`.

If you have a mismatch between dimensions, lengths, and attributes of the arguments you should not expect it to work.

If you put your result options in a `list()`, they can be recycled properly to the length of your vector and this will actually work:

```
ifelse(v==1, list(hp), list(hp0))
# [[1]]
#   size italic bold underlined color shading fontname fontname_cs fontname_eastasia
# 1   NA     NA TRUE         NA    NA  yellow       NA          NA                NA
#   fontname.hansi vertical_align
# 1             NA       baseline
# 
# [[2]]
#   size italic bold underlined color shading fontname fontname_cs fontname_eastasia
# 1   NA     NA   NA         NA    NA      NA       NA          NA                NA
#   fontname.hansi vertical_align
# 1             NA       baseline
```

> Is there some restrictions of the types of values ifelse() can return?

Yes, `ifelse` has trouble with functions. Again, rom the `?ifelse` help page (emphasis mine):

> The `srcref` attribute of functions is handled specially: if `test` is a simple true result and `yes` evaluates to a function with `srcref` attribute, `ifelse` returns `yes` including its attribute (the same applies to a false `test` and `no` argument). This functionality is only for backwards compatibility, **the form `if(test) yes else no` should be used whenever `yes` and `no` are functions**.

Generally, `ifelse` is good for vectors. For a length-one condition `if(){}else{}` is better. For things that don't go well in vectors, like functions, apply family functions or `purrr` functions are probably better.

Comment: Yes, I started with the question in the first sentence, just adding edits now.

Comment: Many thanks Gregor.  I'm afraid the references to srcref are totally over my head, but I assume this this would be the explanation as to why wrapping them in list() works?  wrt the embolden text, that can only work if ```test``` is a scaler, surely?

Comment: Yes, I don't get the `srcref` stuff either, my other takeaway from the bold is "don't try to use `ifelse` to make a list of functions". But lists of functions are things that are rarely useful. (And yes, test condition for `if()` must be of length 1.)